# Windows 10 Huge windows PageFile, how to limited it

Tags: windows-10, disk-space, pagefile

My Windows PC alerted me with low harddisc space, and when I scan hard drives with TreeSize tool, I realize that windows keeps a huge pagefile.sys file, that is 18.2 GB and keep growing.

Why is this pagefile is so big and how can I limited it to a specific max. size like 5 GB maxmium?

[image]

Comment: That's really not a massive pagefile size. How much RAM do you have? How teeny is your boot drive?

Comment: Windows 10 Automatic Page File size works really well and is related to the memory you have. You can make it smaller as an answer here says, but then your disk may begin to trash as a result.

Comment: @John - agreed. but if the system is complaining over a few GB, it's already being thrashed to death. Best guess 128GB SSD. The manufacturers sold those to millions of people who didn't know any better. They should be called to account for it imnsho </rant>  ;)

Comment: If the page file keeps growing, it is possible that there is some program running that has a memory leak. Although it isn't the ideal tool for it, you could use Task Manager to see if some process is using an exorbitant amount of memory.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - indeed. But we're still back to *16GB is by no means exorbitant*. Chrome could use that in an hour. Though I have RAM & SSD to spare, so it's not any kind of worry, my Memory used is currently 47GB, of 64. Because of that, my current swap used [after 8 days' uptime] is still 0 bytes. The OP is suffering from 'under-specced machine' not 'too much swap'.

Comment: I will echo the warnings that limiting the page file to a specific size might end up masking a real problem like a memory leak.

Comment: Using memory is not leaking memory. OP has a 64-bit OS. 64-bit OS thinks it can use anything it likes. It's not the OS at fault.

Comment: @Tetsujin But leaking memory is using memory.

Comment: Quick way to test for leaks… quit all apps.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open the System Properties dialog (right-click `Start`, `System`, select `Advanced system settings` on the right).

[image]

2. On the `Advanced` tab, click `Settings` under the performance section

[image]

3. On the `Advanced` tab of `Performance Options` click `Change` under the `Virtual memory` section

[image]

4. Disable `Automatically manage paging file size for all drives`
5. Use the `Custom size` radio button to open up the `Initial size` and `Maximum size` fields

[image]

6. Specify your values, taking heed of the `Recommended` value at the bottom of the dialog, click `set` and close the dialog boxes.

If you have additional drives, you can also specify a different disk for the pagefile. This is preferable when you have an SSD as your boot drive, as paging to file frequently can reduce the life of an SSD.

Comment: I like this answer, it's technically correct, but it ignores the elephant in the room. Why is the puter complaining about disk space? Because the disk is too full.

Comment: If you have plenty of ram, you don't need to page. Windows just likes to have its safety blankets...

Answer (score 1):

Attention: The pagefile is required for Windows full functionality.

For example, in case of a crash (BSOD), Windows will keep the crash
dump in the pagefile until the computer is restarted.
A too small pagefile will effectively mean disabling crash dumps.

As another example, the system commit limit is the sum of
physical memory (RAM) and all page files combined.
This limit is the maximal memory amount that can be allocated to Windows
and all tasks. If the pagefile is too small, tasks won't be able to ask
for much more memory than the available RAM.

Your pagefile is currently being managed by Windows, so it will increase
in size according to the needs of the running processes.
Its large size might mean that your workload requires more memory than
is physically available.

I recommend reading the Microsoft article of
[How to determine the appropriate page file size for 64-bit versions of Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/determine-appropriate-page-file-size).

Before reducing the pagefile too much, you may also:

- Add more RAM, or
- Allocate page file space on another disk than `C:`.

The total page files space on all disks that I recommend is
RAM plus 257 MB, enough for a complete crash dump.
Although many recommendations say rather 1.5 times the RAM, I believe
that if the RAM is large (as available on modern computers),
the above amount should be enough.

Comment: I've always gone by the 1.5x the amount of RAM, ever since Windows95. Oddly in my screenshots, the recommended is 4GB. This machine has 32GB of RAM.

Comment: @spikey_richie: The 4GB you have counseled concord with the "Minimum page file size" in the Microsoft article, which is "RAM ÷ 8". Windows will increase it when required. So you either didn't have any BSOD (lucky you), or your dump setting is minimal.