# The Adobe Desktop Service process is taking 7 GB of RAM: how can I disable it?

Tags: windows-7, memory

The Adobe Desktop Service process is taking 7 GB of RAM: how can I disable it?

The gif below shows it is taking 7 GB of RAM (the computer has 16 GB of RAM, killing the Adobe Desktop Service process was taking 86-42=44% of it, which represents 0.44*16=7.0 GB):

[image]

I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Installed Adobe products:

[image]

Comment: I am sorry but based on what the gif shows I don't see where the 7GB RAM are mentioned. Adobe Desktop Service has a working set size of about 200 MB the of of about 500 MB how does that sum up to 7GB? The physical memory usage shows something complete different and includes caches so it is expected to be at 80 to 90%. There are hundred of similar posts here on Superuser asking effectively the same question...

Comment: Out of curiosity only, is this causing an issue?

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions yes when the physical memory gets too busy, other programs start crashing.

Comment: @Robert "it is expected to be at 80 to 90%" not at all on my OS.

Comment: @Ramhound I did install some Adobe products. Do you need to know the specific Adobe products have installed?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt other processes don't have a problem even at 90% RAM usage as long there is a page file matching the RAM size. Based on what you describe I would assume you have disabled it, correct?

Comment: @Robert correct

Comment: CC 2018 isn't guaranteed compatible with Win 7. Both your CC & OS need updating. Win10 is still free & you're paying by the month for CC, so your upgrade costs are nil.

Comment: Windows 10 is still free? Do you have a link?

Comment: Sadly, I suspect you will need to contact Adobe but I suspect you will hear that it is unsupported blah blah blah. Sorry

Comment: The only potential work around I can think of, given your SO score is to create a polling task in the back ground that monitors usage. If it uses over N GB, restart the service.

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions That the upgrade still works is a public secret and you can be sure MS also knows it but there is no official statement. But that Windows 10 installer accepts Win7/8 keys can be seen as an indicator that upgrading is still allowed.

Comment: @Robert which Windows 10 editions are free?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Windows 10 is not free but the common editions for end users can still be upgraded from Win7/8 as far as I know. Just download the Win10 installer and perform the upgrade. A full backup is of course recommended before starting such a task.

Comment: And because of the page file please read this answer: https://superuser.com/a/1663725/62676 Mem mgmt of Win10is still more or less the same as Win7. This can also affect the behavior you have observed.

Comment: windows 10 for free 2021: https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/upgrade-to-windows-10-free

Comment: does this help ? https://community.adobe.com/t5/download-install/how-to-stop-creative-cloud-from-launching-at-start-up/m-p/9969461

Comment: @1NN thanks, this is just for Windows 10 Home, no pro. Also anyway some of my programs run on Windows 10. thanks for the adobe link!

Comment: Franck - the upgrade is 'like to like' if you upgrade pro you get pro. I haven't done it for a while, but I have done it many times since the official free period ended in 2017, always successfully.