# pagefile.sys and hiberfile .sys grew a collective 50 gigabytes overnight. How can I restore them to their original size?

Tags: windows-10

I left my computer to do some pretty intense computations and when i cane back i found out that pagefile had grown to an astonishing 70 gigabytes and hiberfile 13 gigabytes. How can I make them go back to their normal size without causing instability?

Comment: [disk space - Windows 10 Huge windows PageFile, how to limited it - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1663707/windows-10-huge-windows-pagefile-how-to-limited-it)

Comment: [How to Change the Size of Hiberfil.Sys in Windows 10 - MajorGeeks](https://www.majorgeeks.com/content/page/change_the_size_of_hiberfil_sys.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 10 Huge windows PageFile, how to limited it](https://superuser.com/questions/1663707/windows-10-huge-windows-pagefile-how-to-limited-it)